# Django FieldError at /admin/app/modelClass/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I think I'm not repeating the question as I couldn't find an answer to my question.

My Model class in **models.py** is as follows:

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    users = User.objects.all()
    Instance_ID = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    Service_ID = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

    Reference_ID = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
```

and the **admin.py** is as follows:

```
class UserDetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user','Instance_ID','Service_ID','Reference_ID')
    search_fields = ('users__User','Instance_ID','Service_ID','Reference_ID')
```

How do I search the user fields? If I try only 'user' or 'user_id' in the search_fields, I'm getting the following error.

> TypeError at /admin/app/UserDetail/ -----> "Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains"

and if I try 'User__users' or 'users__User' or 'users' in the search_fields, I'm getting the following Field Error:

> FieldError at /admin/app/UserDetail/ ----> "Cannot resolve keyword 'users' into field. Choices are: Reference_ID, Service_ID, Instance_ID, user, user_id"

what am I doing wrong? Can someone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to have a field reference something like User.objects.all(). What you probably want is a view that uses the query as a search field for user, and then would call User.objects.filter(username=queryparameter).

Comment: Yes I actually removed it just now. I'm working only with     'user=models.OneToOneField(User)' and the search field as 'user__username'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the stock User class, "Users" isn't a field on that class, so that won't work.

I think using users__username as a search field will work, but have not tested.

Comment: Thanks @Jason champion, yes that solved my problem, but with a small correction, It worked with 'user__username'